# Transaction automation with certain condition in smart contract

Tags: rest, websocket, backend, solidity

I am developing and blockchain gaming service now and I want to send some tokens to a winner automatically at the end of game, and at specific times.

```
/*
 * This function should be called every X days
 */
function sendTokens() public {
// We send some tokens to an array of players
}
```

Currently, I am doing this using traditional Backend technologies such as setInterval and WebSocket - however, this is a centralized method.

What is the best way to do that? What is the professional way?

Answer (score 2):

Every state-change that happens on-chain needs to be triggered by a transaction. Therefore, to run a smart contract function on a schedule, after a specific event, or some other if-else trigger, you need someone to spend gas.

With that being said, you have two options:

### 1. Decentralized Automation

You can use a decentralized network of [oracles](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85178/what-is-a-blockchain-oracle) to call smart contracts. Using [Chainlink Keepers](https://keepers.chain.link/) can call the function you specified at any time or event trigger focused. The oracles pay the gas associated with the call, and you pay for a subscription model to the Chainlink nodes.

The way, you're contract stays decentralized all the way down to the automation level, and you never have to worry about a centralized actor intentionally not sending a transaction.

You'd setup the trigger using `checkUpkeep` by defining in your contract what event you want to wait for (like time based, some event based, etc), and then what you want to do when that trigger is hit in `performUpkeep`.

An example would look as such:

This contract runs `performUpkeep` every `interval` seconds.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

// KeeperCompatible.sol imports the functions from both ./KeeperBase.sol and
// ./interfaces/KeeperCompatibleInterface.sol
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/KeeperCompatible.sol";

contract Counter is KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    /**
    * Public counter variable
    */
    uint public counter;

    /**
    * Use an interval in seconds and a timestamp to slow execution of Upkeep
    */
    uint public immutable interval;
    uint public lastTimeStamp;

    constructor(uint updateInterval) {
      interval = updateInterval;
      lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

      counter = 0;
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
        // We don't use the checkData in this example. The checkData is defined when the Upkeep was registered.
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        //We highly recommend revalidating the upkeep in the performUpkeep function
        if ((block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval ) {
            lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
        // We don't use the performData in this example. The performData is generated by the Keeper's call to your checkUpkeep function
    }
}
```

Other options include Gelato.

### 2. Centralized Automation

You can also have "traditional" infrastructure call your functions on a schedule, just keep in mind this means that you are relying on a centralized actor in your contracts.

There are forms of centralized automation that you can take such as:

- Your own server/set of scripts
- Openzeppelin Defender
- Tenderly
- Incentive Mechanisms for people to call your functions
  etc

Disclaimer: I work at Chainlink Labs